In React Native, the Android View Component is not visible without a style
I am creating an Android View Component to use in React Native. However, I noticed that some components are not visible in React Native. For example, I created a very simple TextView as an Android View Component to use in React Native, but it was not visible.
public class MyCustomView extends FrameLayout {

    private TextView textView;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        addView(textView);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <MyCustomView text="Hello, World!" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

While investigating the cause, I came across the following issue.
Adding Native UI component to React Native does nothing
However, once I added a style to the component, it became visible. While the issue is resolved, I don't understand the reason behind it. Why doesn't the component appear unless a style is applied?
